# Close the parents's parent window

Tags: javascript, window

Here is scenario

window1 -Opens-> window2 -Opens-> window3

What I need the an operation where in windows closes in following order

window3 window2 window1

The operation should be initialed from the window3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a javascript function as below

```
function windowClose()
{
    parent.windowClose(); //Parent is parent window, need to check whether current has parent
    window.close();
}
```

Place this function in all windows